# How to make this dropdownbutton widget reusable?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the dropdownbutton widget below, with a futurebuilder that reads a list from a google spreadsheet. The widget works good as intended.

I want to reuse this widget within the app, and simply pass a different Future

As example, I want to call the same widget, but pass different lists
mydropdownbutton ( futureList1 ),
mydropdownbutton ( futureList2 ),
mydropdownbutton ( futureList3 ),

```
//========================================================
// WIDGET: FUTURE DROPDOWN MENU + FUTURE LIST
//--------------------------------------------------------
  class dropDownButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    const dropDownButtonWidget({ Key? key,}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    State<dropDownButtonWidget> createState() => _dropDownButtonWidgetState();
  }
// --------------------------------------------------------
  class _dropDownButtonWidgetState extends State<dropDownButtonWidget> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(future: futureList(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData){ List? futureDataList = snapshot.data;
                  futureDataList ??= ['Loading']; //if snapshot is null
                  return buildDropdownButton(dropdownList: futureDataList );
              }else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
              }else {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
          }
        )
      );
    }
    //----------------------------------
    // DROPDOWNBUTTON EXTRACTED METHOD
      DropdownButton<Object> buildDropdownButton({required List dropdownList}) {
        String defaultValue = dropdownList.first; //DEFAULT SELECTED ITEM
          return DropdownButton(
                  value: defaultValue,
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() => defaultValue = value.toString()),
                  items: dropdownList.map((items) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(value: items, child: Text(items));
                    }).toList(),
                  );
       }
    //----------------------------------
  }
//=============================================

//=============================================
//FUTURE LIST FOR THE DROPDOWN MENU
//=============================================
  Future<List> futureList() async {
    var items = await ScheduleInfo.mx_schedule_WEEKDAYS_as_List(debugONOFF: 1);
    return items;}
//=============================================
```

How can I make this widget modular and reusable?

Comment: What do you mean by reusable?

Comment: @Anye it means that the same code can be reused, just like a reusable function sumFunct(a,b){return a+b}. You can call this function as many times as needed. Widgets also can be reused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Community... after few hours of reading and testing, I found the solution to my own question. I am posting the solution for anyone else needing it.

Probably, my code can be improved, I welcome suggestions.

My question above has a working code for a dropdown button widget (fully working as today), using a Future

Below, my own answer, the same widget transformed into a reusable modular widget.

( This works only with future lists (async) )

Simple SCREEN WIDGET (with nested dropdownbutton widgets):

```
class Screen01 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Screen01({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen01> createState() => _Screen01State();
}

class _Screen01State extends State<Screen01> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child:
        Flex(
          direction: Axis.horizontal, 
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

          children:
            [ // each time you call the widget, you can provide a different future list          
              dropDownButtonWidgetModular(futureList: dropdownFutureList()), 

              SizedBox(width: 50,),

              dropDownButtonWidgetModular(futureList: anotherFutureList())
            ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

DROPDOWNBUTTON WIDGET:

```
//========================================================
// WIDGET: FUTURE DROPDOWN MENU + FUTURE LIST
//--------------------------------------------------------
class dropDownButtonWidgetModular extends StatefulWidget {

  final Future<List> futureList; // ===> ADDED FUTURE LIST
  const dropDownButtonWidgetModular({ Key? key, required this.futureList}) : super(key: key); // ===> ADDED REQUIRED FUTURE LIST

  @override
  State<dropDownButtonWidgetModular> createState() => _dropDownButtonWidgetModularState(chosenFutureList: futureList);
}
// --------------------------------------------------------
class _dropDownButtonWidgetModularState extends State<dropDownButtonWidgetModular> {

  Future<List> chosenFutureList; // ===> ADDED FUTURE LIST
  String? defaultValue;

  _dropDownButtonWidgetModularState({required this.chosenFutureList}); // ===> ADDED REQUIRED FUTURE LIST

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child:
    FutureBuilder(future: chosenFutureList, // ===> ADDED FUTURE LIST
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){ List? futureDataList = snapshot.data;
            futureDataList ??= ['Loading']; //if snapshot is null
            return buildDropdownButton(dropdownList: futureDataList );
          }else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()));
          }else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        }
    )
    );
  }
  //----------------------------------
  // DROPDOWNBUTTON EXTRACTED METHOD
  DropdownButton<Object> buildDropdownButton({required List dropdownList}) {

    defaultValue ??= dropdownList.first; //DEFAULT SELECTED ITEM

    return DropdownButton(
      value: defaultValue,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() => defaultValue = value.toString()),
      items: dropdownList.map((items) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(value: items, child: Text(items));
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
//----------------------------------
}
//=============================================
```

I commented some of the changes made from my original question

Answer (score 0):

you can send the future to this widget's constructor. first you declare a variable and set it to constructor. then you can reference that variable in the state of that class by `widget.variable` keyword. something like this

```
class dropDownButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    final variable;
    dropDownButtonWidget(this.variable);
    const dropDownButtonWidget({ Key? key,}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    State<dropDownButtonWidget> createState() => _dropDownButtonWidgetState();
  }

class _dropDownButtonWidgetState extends State<dropDownButtonWidget> {
widget.variable //whatever you want to do with it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it's giving an error: that the constructor already exist. Even though I fixed it by merging the two constructors, I am still unable to create a modular widget. From my readings, sharing variables seems more complex. Probably, I'll need to use widget inheritance. Currently looking into a resolution.